# Tensorflow c++, issue with tensors and feeding

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I am very new to TensorFlow C++ API and trying to just build a very simple graph in Python and load/test it in C++ API. Here is the python code to create the graph:

```
with tf.Session() as sess: 
   a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2,2], name='a')
   b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2,2], name='b')
   c = tf.matmul(a, b, name="c")

   sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, 'models/', 'graph.pb', as_text=False)
```

and here is the C code to load and run the graph:

```
Tensor a(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({2,2}));

Tensor b(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({2,2}));
std::vector<std::pair<string, tensorflow::Tensor>> inputs = {
  { "a", a },
  { "b", b },
};

std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;

status = session->Run(inputs, {"c"}, {}, &outputs);
```

However I get this error message:

> ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:500] Check failed: 1 ==
>   NumElements() (1 vs. 4)Must have a one element tensor

What could be the problem? I noticed if I define my tensors in he python and C++ as [1,1], it goes through without any problem!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [here](https://medium.com/@hamedmp/exporting-trained-tensorflow-models-to-c-the-right-way-cf24b609d183#.t9iq9asfs), I tried to explain everything completely 
 To summarize you should use 'freeze_graph' file to make trained variables constant and then import it in your C++ file.